# Raspberry PI SMB User from Windows 10

Tags: samba

I'm at my wit's end. I have an external drive connected to a raspberry pi 4 which I am ultimately trying to connect to from a Windows 10 computer via samba.

Using [this script](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd) I was finally able to get the raspberry pi to be visible to the windows computer.

However, I cannot seem to access any of the shares (haven't even started with the usb drive). When I provide the username/pwd for the share, I get the following error:
[image]

I have the same smb.conf for a raspberry pi zero and it seems to be working fine (though I remember that being a pain as well).

My smb.conf file is the following: (comments removed)

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   min protocol = SMB2
   protocol = SMB3
   wins support = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[PiShare]
 comment=Raspberry Pi Share
 path=/home/pi/
 browseable=Yes
 writeable=Yes
 only guest=no
 create mask=0777
 directory mask=0777
 public=no



[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
```

When attempted to connect to the [homes] share, I get a "Windows cannot access \HOST\homes" error, likely because it is attempting to connect as guest which windows disables by default policy.

Comment: Did you add a user to the Samba accounts using the `smbpasswd -a` command?  Normally, I would add the Pi user unless the data was sensitive and then I would create a specific one and a complex password...

Comment: Yes, I did add a username.

Comment: Well, the worst possible thing has happened - it now works but I have no idea why (just some reboots and resets did the trick)! Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Sounds like the Samba service was not running or had read the config files.  I honestly cannot remember if it’s auto start but it’s unlikely to read the config file dynamically even if it is running. A `sudo servicectl reload smbd’ or `sudo servicectl restart smbd` should do it (not 100% if sudo needed).  I normally use the restart option as some things do not read updates with reload...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a hunch it has to do with the bottom part of the error message (multiple connections aren't allowed). I read on some other SO question that logging onto the server will count as a connection and make it impossible to connect again. Not sure, but I think that may be the problem because I can't connect with my second computer at this time.

Comment: Very strange - Windows computers do not normally know about connections of other computers unless there is an exclusive lock (folder / file / record level) - even R/O locks (i.e. only 1 link can write - all others are read only) should not complain about connections.  Samba also does not care about the same user being used to connect from different machines.  I only have one Windows machine handy (and that's a VM on a Mac) - I can do some tests Monday for you if I cannot find anything else tonight / tomorrow night as I should be able to 'borrow' wifes laptop then :-)

Comment: Typical - have a look at https://www.golinuxhub.com/2013/12/multiple-connections-to-server-or/ It's saying use `net use` to id the links and then `net use /delete` to tidy up.  No idea if that still exists in Win 10. I also wonder if one map is by name and one by IP - known that created issues in Win 7 and before https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f3ee2c61-a5c7-48b3-a3bf-23ea323da699/connecting-to-multiple-shares-on-a-single-server-with-multiple-credentials-system-error-1219- (spent many weeks with buggy AD/DNS/DHCP  messes before today).

Comment: YES! You saved the day, this totally was the issue. Please make this an answer so I can accept it. Given how many answers are out there for similar problems, I think it would be helpful for others. Thank you so much, this was the cause of so much frustration.